# How to plot histogram in gnuplot with log y axis

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, logarithm

There are many instructions to plot historams in gnuplot.
My data has some bins that have 0 entries, others are huge.
I need to plot the histogram with log y axis, but that crashes with the 0-bins.

Any way to increment the bins by 1 so that there is none that has 0 entry?

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: Could you please provide a _short_ script and an excerpt of the data file, which shows the problem?

Comment: Can you comment more on your problem? For me the `set log y` and `with boxes` works without problem for data with `0` value